# Jenkins triggering a build using API returns status code 200

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins ver. 1.532.2

Possibly related to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18407

When I go to my job and put "api" at the end I get the following text

> To programmatically schedule a new build, post to this URL. If the
>   build has parameters, post to this URL and provide the parameters as
>   form data. Either way, the successful queueing will result in 201
>   status code with Location HTTP header pointing the URL of the item in
>   the queue. By polling the api/xml sub-URL of the queue item, you can
>   track the status of the queued task. Generally, the task will go
>   through some state transitions, then eventually it becomes either
>   cancelled (look for the "cancelled" boolean property), or gets
>   executed (look for the "executable" property that typically points to
>   the AbstractBuild object.)

So I have two jobs one with parameters and one without parameters. When I trigger a job without the parameters I get the behavior exactly described as above i.e, a status code of 201 with a "Location" header which tells me the queue item.

However this does not appear to be the case for a job with parameters. When this is done I get a status code of 200 (which kinda means that it was not queued) however I can see that in the UI the job got triggered fine. Has anyone faced the same problem before anywhere else?

Why is Location Header important?
"Location" header is *THE MOST* important piece of information. So Jenkins is telling me OKAY without telling me what is the build number (or the queue item number) that got triggered. One assumption that can work under some circumstances is to trigger a build and follow the "latestBuild" but it won't work in the context of concurrent builds.

Comment: HTTP 200 means "OK". Perhaps this is expected?

Comment: My problem is less about the 200/201 status codes. They both mean OK/QUEUED. My problem is that in the case of status 200/build with parameters the "Location" header is not populated and I updated the question with why "Location" is the most important header.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is old but I have been experiencing the same problem. I also receive the status code 200. However if you look at the returned data (my data is in json format) you will find a queueItem section -

[image: Fiddler capture of response]

By querying the url given in this section appended with the api suffix  `http://myjenkins/queue/item/4/api/xml/` I got the information I wanted. When first querying the api it may not contain the information you require but by polling this url, once a build has been started there will be an executable section that contains the url of the newly created build -

[image: XML from polling url]

It's worth pointing out that it seems the queue url has a limited lifetime after which it is not available (if no longer in the queue) - I'm not sure how long this is or whether it is configurable but seemed to be about 5 minutes for me. Hope this helps.